# How to ping a user with their user id in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When I get a statement from one of my bot commands and it "@'s" another user, I receive that as their user id. When this happens I want to ping that user using that id, how would I go about doing that?

I take the messages I get and put them in array, so when someone says "@soandso is a nerd" it becomes [ '<@', 'stringofnumbers>', 'is', 'a', 'nerd' ].

I thought originally to put the "<@" in a new array as an "@" and then adding the username to that, but I don't know how to get the username from the userid.

Comment: Have a look at [`message.mentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `message.author.toString()`

So for sending a message:   `message.channel.send(message.author.toString())`

For saving a username in your log:  `console.log(message.author.toString())`

Answer (score 2):

Something like  this would work

```
 bot.on("message", async message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    message.channel.send(`${message.author.toString()} This is my reply`);

 });
```

just  call the  toString function  on the message's  author.

Edit: I think i missunderstood your question,  if you need to get the User from the ID you can do the following.

```
 message.guild.members.get('ID HERE').displayName
```

and that should return the user's display name from the ID, provided that the user is in the server that the command was sent in.